# What/who is missing?

Tags: word, word-search

### [image]

For alternative resolution:

> ```
> W   D   C   V   A   I   O   H   J   N   K   L   R   Q   X   C   R   I   N   O   U   G   H   K   L   S   A   A   Z   A
> R   E   E   T   U   P   A   S   X   C   V   Z   U   I   P   A   Q   Y   F   L   C   X   X   X   N   M   K   L   I   Q
> T   F   R   A   A   S   D   X   F   C   L   Q   B   Q   A   Q   W   Y   A   T   F   T   C   H   S   F   G   R   W   B
> I   E   Y   R   P   V   C   S   Z   X   O   N   N   I   R   A   E   H   Q   Z   G   G   G   N   R   E   C   H   S   V
> L   I   X   I   R   E   J   F   U   W   K   A   G   W   S   A   E   X   W   H   A   Y   X   S   W   G   Q   W   S   Y
> N   U   C   O   P   E   O   H   I   N   G   O   T   E   D   S   R   S   S   N   W   R   T   D   Y   R   D   R   X   A
> S   E   N   V   Y   W   O   K   P   O   L   L   E   O   H   M   L   O   L   I   J   K   L   N   M   O   T   R   X   Q
> M   Z   V   Z   U   R   I   P   Q   N   I   Y   T   T   F   D   T   W   G   B   Y   X   C   V   B   E   M   F   C   V
> Z   T   B   Q   W   T   G   O   A   U   J   W   V   R   G   F   Z   E   L   M   Q   Z   A   W   Q   G   H   V   V   T
> U   S   N   Q   D   K   H   I   Y   J   U   S   F   T   H   H   U   D   U   J   A   I   Y   U   R   O   R   B   B   Z
> B   P   M   W   S   P   J   U   W   M   M   X   P   Z   J   Y   I   C   T   O   U   C   H   I   T   P   E   N   Y   H
> V   P   J   E   A   Y   K   Z   S   I   L   E   R   U   K   R   O   V   T   U   Y   M   M   O   P   L   U   J   X   J
> F   O   K   R   G   F   L   T   X   K   U   D   C   I   L   O   P   F   O   K   Y   U   S   P   A   I   U   U   Q   I
> G   L   L   I   O   U   F   R   W   Q   S   C   V   B   N   L   M   J   N   A   Y   S   C   D   U   F   F   V   H   U
> H   I   Z   Q   Q   Y   D   E   A   R   T   H   D   O   M   G   L   Q   Y   O   X   T   D   U   L   O   A   T   W   W
> E   K   U   T   K   A   R   L   E   O   Z   C   E   P   N   N   K   R   X   P   C   R   F   Z   F   Q   K   G   E   A
> S   M   I   Z   L   L   T   K   D   L   Z   R   Y   A   B   I   H   T   C   P   F   E   G   I   D   H   E   O   R   T
> X   J   O   U   P   M   R   O   C   P   B   F   A   S   V   A   F   T   F   O   G   W   G   K   U   W   R   I   C   E
> Y   U   P   J   I   J   T   H   T   A   R   W   P   D   C   V   D   G   P   L   R   R   H   L   I   P   P   U   D   R
> L   Z   L   G   U   G   G   I   R   Q   G   V   Q   F   D   J   S   B   R   I   E   Q   J   G   U   O   Q   J   C   H
> H   H   O   P   Z   S   M   E   L   L   T   T   P   G   F   K   A   M   I   E   C   L   N   H   Z   T   P   M   V   B
> Q   N   G   H   T   Z   I   W   F   A   V   G   L   H   G   L   Y   J   D   K   S   J   V   I   I   U   O   K   V   V
> T   B   F   S   S   T   N   R   V   Y   F   B   O   J   T   M   X   U   E   M   D   K   B   U   A   S   H   L   M   F
> U   G   S   A   A   H   R   I   T   E   P   T   K   K   R   N   C   K   R   J   F   H   I   T   U   X   K   E   N   R
> Z   T   D   P   T   R   E   N   G   W   R   Z   I   L   E   B   V   I   T   U   A   D   O   Y   H   H   L   T   O   E
> M   R   Y   O   E   E   D   G   B   S   C   H   F   Y   U   V   B   O   G   Z   X   C   P   I   Z   U   I   S   P   D
> K   W   L   H   E   I   H   G   Z   X   D   N   M   I   Y   C   N   Q   B   H   Q   W   T   F   G   J   Z   A   L   C
> F   S   B   N   I   I   K   U   H   E   E   U   J   Y   R   X   M   L   N   G   F   E   P   S   I   G   H   T   X   X
> D   J   J   Z   R   F   R   V   G   H   A   I   O   U   W   E   R   Y   Y   V   B   N   G   F   R   R   W   S   H   Q
> I   R   T   H   Z   C   N   H   O   J   X   V   B   N   M   W   F   G   H   I   Z   K   O   Q   A   Y   S   D   F   Q
> ```

**What or who is missing in this puzzle?**

**HINT:**

> Complete the word search and you will miss something or someone.

Comment: Mind providing a transcription for people who want to solve this in an alternate form?

Comment: How can I do that? @Deusovi

Comment: @D.Mellow You should be able to type it out like `<blockquote><pre>WDCVAIOH...</pre></blockquote>` You won't need double-spaces for line breaks when typing in that and all characters will be fixed-width, so they will line up nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Highlighted images (includes spoilers)

**<sup>*Does not include a final answer</sup>**

Divided by categories:

> **Deadly sins (7 + 1 historical)**
>  <sub>Note: *Gluttony* appears misspelled as *Glutonny* and *Acedia* was not found</sub>
>  [image]

---

> **4 Elements**
>  [image]

---

> **5 Senses**
>  [image]

---

> **The Beatles**
>  [image]

Comment: I edited the question, now it has an answer that you already know, because Ringo should not appear in the word search, but I accidentally include it! (Also corrected the misspelling) Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2):

Corrected with help from Jaap Scherphuis:

What's missing could be

> One of the seven deadly sins. So far I see WRATH and PRIDE (GLUTONNY is present as a misspelling of gluttony; unclear if a mistake or if this is the "missing" word)

There are a number of potential

> red herrings, including SIGHT, TOUCH, SMELL, TASTE, HEARING (five senses) and EARTH, AIR, WATER, FIRE (four elements)

Comment: Some of the other sins are in there as well (pride, gluttony). Could it not just as well be a missing one of those? Or maybe Umami? Maybe wind is not present, but air is?

Comment: Certainly possible - I haven't found all of those. I did search for my answer word and I'm fairly sure it's not in there, but it could be missing items in more than one category.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Also, did you actually find gluttony? So far I've only found a misspelling (glutonny).

Comment: You're right, gluttony is misspelled. I have now found air starting at the top right corner, so you have a full set of the 4 traditional elements.

Comment: Nice. I'll update my answer. Also - I'm new to puzzling: are we to delete comments that reference a possible answer since they aren't behind spoiler tags?

Comment: I don't know if that's the done thing. Personally I'm not a fan of deleting comments unless they are (or become) blatantly wrong or irrelevant. Btw, there's vainglory as one of the sins too.